# CombBox is not populating the ValueMember Properly from MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I have two combobox in my form, using a mysql connection to a remote server.  The first combobox populated nicely.  However, I need the indexid since that is a foreign key to populate a second combobox.  Based on the selection, it will change the data in the second combo (for the xample, i the first combo is for car makes, then the models of each make gets filled, so if I choose Nissan, the models will then have Altima, Maxima, Sentra, ... but if I chose Toyota, the combo will then show Corolla, Camry, Prius, ...)

My foreign key is always -1 for some reason.  I am using the selectindex change method, but it keeps crashing/ bc the value is always -1.

I am very new to MySQL in C# and eager to learn.  Any help is appreciated.  The code is below.

```
    private void cboMake_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboMake.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            cboModel.Enabled = true;
        else
            cboModel.Enabled = false;

        // get the foreign key value of the model id to get the make for each brand to populate here            
        // MessageBox.Show(cboModel.ValueMember);
        // right now selectindex always shows -1.  why?
        // if it changes, you need to then enable the right cbo, else, disable.
        // but also, you need the mid, fk, so you can then do a new sql statement with the where clause to populate it.
        int fk = cboModel.SelectedIndex;            
        string connStr = "server=123.456.7.8;user=root;database=car;port=3306; password=nowayjose";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM cs_model WHERE mid='fk'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            cboMake.DataSource = dt;
            cboMake.DisplayMember = "model";
            cboMake.ValueMember = "mmid";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MySQL Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = "server=123.456.7.8;user=root;database=car;port=3306; password=nowayjose";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM cs_make";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            cboMake.DataSource = dt;
            cboMake.DisplayMember = "make";
            cboMake.ValueMember = "mid";               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MySQL Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you repopulating the list each time you clicked something in the box? Since your `cboMake.DataSource` is a DataTable, can't you simply retrieve this value? (`DataTable myData = cboMake.DataSource as DataTable`)

Comment: Is `cboMake.ValueMember="mmid"` correct?  Looks like it should be "mid" based on the query.

Comment: I don't know, I tried to follow some example and don't know what I am doing (I guess that part is obvious)

Comment: `mysql> select * from cs_model where mid=13;
+------+-----+-----------+
| mmid | mid | model     |
+------+-----+-----------+
|  173 |  13 | Accord    |
|  174 |  13 | Civic     |
|  175 |  13 | CR-V      |
|  176 |  13 | Element   |
|  177 |  13 | Fit       |
|  178 |  13 | Odyssey   |
|  179 |  13 | Pilot     |
|  180 |  13 | Ridgeline |
|  181 |  13 | S2000     |
+------+-----+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, not used to markdown, but mid is foreign key, mmid is the primary key..

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the new value member.  ; Parameter name: value   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_ValueMember(String value);    at Car.frmMain.cboMake_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void cboMake_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int foreignKey = (int)cboMake.SelectedIndex +1;   // i forgot to cast the int from string since the database was tinyint, it still returns string in c#
        string fk = foreignKey.ToString();   // since i need the string for the query, back it goes, but i needed to do arithmetic 
        string connStr = "server=10.18.30.1;user=notroot;database=car;port=3306;password=password";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM cs_model WHERE mid=" + fk;   // forgot to escape out of the string (used to php $var style within double quotes)
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);                    
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            cboModel.DataSource = dt;           // i had cboModel by a silly mistake
            cboModel.DisplayMember = "model";
            cboModel.ValueMember = "mmid";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MySQL Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        conn.Close();            
    }
```

Comment: Well,. I meant I had cboMake above on the last datasource so it was pulling the wrong data... So yeah, silly mistakes.  I guess if I stop staring at it for awhile, and trace my code it would help myself, and it did.  But thanks to all for helping, I did learn a lot from this endeavour

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but  considering code provided, just a guess :

```
 private void cboMake_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int fk = cboModel.SelectedIndex;  // ?????         
      ..... 
    }
```

You access here **cboModel**, which is not that one whom item was actually selected. At least lookin on event name **cboMake**_SelectedIndexChanged, seems to me that you should look on **cboMake** selected index.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I change the car make ComboBox, it should update the car model ComboBox.  I think my selected index is incorrect (and so is my code that enabled the model, since my index values are wrong (essentially, if no make is selected, there is no model to choose from, hence it being disabled at first))...  But, the cboMake.ValueMember = "mid"; i think is being updated wrong.  i need to access its value as the foreign key later on.

Comment: @Jonathan:  *in this code* you're inside slected index chaned of the cboMake. cboMake, as much as I understood, should set cboModel data. So you should query in this code, cboMake imo....